# Putting Data from Cookie into a List<string> with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, list, cookies

I'm trying to make a shoppingcart using a cookie. 
Every item has a Id which is put into the cookie. 
Now I'm trying to put my cookie values into a List but I can't really find how to do it.
I want every value to be in a seperate index, is this possible?

Making the cookie:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Adding a Id on buttonclick:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.Add("", "3");
        Response.Write(Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.ToString());;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    public void SetCookiesList(List<string> listOfCookies)
    {
        var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        HttpCookie cookie = req.Cookies["cookieName"];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            var cookieVal = cookie.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieVal))
                listOfCookies.Add(cookieVal);
        }
    }
```